# Changing QGraphicsItems position within the scene event handler?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

I am using

```
void QGraphicsItem::installSceneEventFilter(QGraphicsItem * filterItem);
```

to set an event filter on a QgraphicsItem (see [itemChanged() in QGraphicsItem for a many different items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19860582/itemchanged-in-qgraphicsitem-for-a-many-different-items))

Now, for some of these items, I'd like to restrict the movement, i.e. change the x and y position of the item so that the user would be restricted in some area in the object move.

I first tried to modify the event with:

```
(static cast <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent*>(event))->setPos(QPoint(150, watched->y()));
```

The whole handler beiing:

```
bool generic_graphic_item::sceneEventFilter(QGraphicsItem* watched, QEvent* event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouseMove)
    {
        (static_cast<QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent*>(event))->setPos(QPointF(150, watched->y()));
        //emit my_item_changed(watched); // signal that the item was moved
        emit(item_pos_changed(watched, watched->x(), watched->y()));
    }
    return false; // pass the event to the original target item
}
```

But it did not work. I was not really sure either about the specific event class hiding behind a `QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouseEvent`.

I then tried to call `watched->setX()` and `watched->setY()` within the event handler, but that was not very popular... which I can understand...

Is it possible to restrict the movement within the scene event handler?

I have read that `QGraphicsItem::itemChange()` can be used to do that, but then I am back into the problem described in  '[itemChanged() in QGraphicsItem for a many different items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19860582/itemchanged-in-qgraphicsitem-for-a-many-different-items)', i.e. how can I have this common to many items without subclassing each of them...

many thanks,

Comment: Thanks Merlin069 for taking the time to answer.
If I use QEvent::GraphicsSceneMove as you suggested, I don't even get the signal item_pos_changed with the new position. My code works for that, i.e. the item_pos_changed signal is emited.
But I don't know how to change the event to the mouse position I want, In the example above only alowing moves along an horisontal line with x=150

Answer (score 1):

The code you post in this question is responding to the event of the moving of the mouse. For what you're describing that you want to do, I suggest you check for the event of a widget being moved with **QEvent::GraphicsSceneMove**: -

```
if(event->type() == QEvent::GraphicsSceneMove)
{
    // set the position of the item.
}
```